# memory allocation for n pointers of newly defined data type

Tags: c, pointers, types, malloc

I need to:

a) define a data type (of my own choice) called *mytype*.

b) and have a function getmemory(int n), reserve memory for n values of type *mytype* and return a pointer. I have implemented this as shown below:

```c
typedef int mytype;
// b) 
mytype *getmemory(int n)
{
    mytype *p;
    //allocate space for n values of mytype.
    p = (mytype *)malloc(n * sizeof(mytype));
    return p;
}
```

Now I want to change the code to reserve and return memory for n pointers to *mytype*. 
I'm not sure how to do that, I have searched a lot on the internet (also on StackOverflow), but I'm still not sure how to solve the task best. Below I have two possible solutions and would like to know which one is the right one.

### **Solutions:**

**1. Solution:**

```c
mytype **getmemoryForNPointer(int n_pointers, int n_mytype)
{
    mytype **p = NULL;
    p = (mytype **) malloc(n_pointers  * sizeof(mytype *));

    return p;
}
```

**2. Solution**

```c
mytype **getmemoryForNPointer(int n_mytype, int n_pointers)
{
    mytype **p = NULL; 

    //allocate n pointers to mytype first:
    p = (mytype **) malloc(n_pointers * sizeof(mytype*));
    //I'm not sure the for loop belongs in there.   
    for (int i = 0; i < n_pointers; i++)
    {
        // For each such pointer, allocate space for n mytype-values.
        p[i] = (mytype *)malloc(n_mytype * sizeof(mytype));
    }
    return p;
}
```

---

is the following code equivalent to the second code?

```c
mytype **getmemoryForNPointer(int n_mytype, int n_pointers)
{
    mytype *p[n_pointers];
    for (int i = 0; i < n_pointers; i++)
    {
        p[i] = (mytype *)malloc(n_mytype* sizeof(mytype));
    }

    return p;
}
```

Comment: it is useless to cast the return of `malloc`, and rather than to initialize with `NULL` then to immediately reassign just do `mytype **p = malloc(n_pointers * sizeof(mytype*));` . Also in *getmemory* do directly `return malloc(n * sizeof(mytype));` except if you want to check `malloc` does not return `NULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your 'solutions' are correct, after a fashion (but see here: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/10871073)).

The difference is that the first allocates the array of pointers but then does nothing with those pointers (i.e. they will all contain undefined and unusable addresses). You could improve this version by using [`calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) in place of `malloc`, which would initialize all those pointers to `NULL` (so that each can then be tested, elsewhere in your code, before trying to dereference it).

The second solution also allocates memory for each block of data and assigns the addresses of those blocks to the pointers. In that sense, the second is more *complete*, but not necessarily more *correct*.

But, don't forget to free the data when you're done:

```c
void freememoryForNPointer(mytype** ptr, int n_pointers)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n_pointers; i++) free(ptr[i]);
    free(ptr);
}
```

Comment: *more correct* : that depends on the goal, it can be worst too ^^ What about to just initialize to NULL pointers (e.g. using `calloc` rather than `malloc`) ? Without knowing more about the goal we cannot know

Comment: thanks for this detailed answer :-)

since I did not learn 'calloc' in the lecture, I do not want to use it. Anyway, Is it a must to define an array of pointers? or could I reserve space for a pointer to mytype without defining an array of pointers?

Comment: If you want to reserve memory for *multiple* blocks of data, then you should use an array of pointers (one for each block, as in your code). Your very first block of code will assign a *single* block of data; in theory, you could just call that multiple times (one for each block) and assign its return value to many, independent pointers, but that would be worse coding style, IMHO.

Comment: ok, i just edited my question, please look at the last part of the post. is this what you meant? Is it a valid but a worse coding style?

Comment: The code you added is just wrong. First, it should return a `mytype**` type; second, I think the `malloc` should use `n_mytype` rather than `n_pointers`; and third, it is returning an address of a **local** memory block, which will be invalid when the function has returned.

Comment: my mistake, I already know that `mytype**` should be returned, but I typed wrong. I have edited the code, so that now `n_mytype' instead of `n_pointers'.  Is it returning an address of a local memory block, because "*p[n_pointers]" is a pointer to stack and not to Heap? so, this was was Static memory allocation ? and if you want to reserve memory for pointers on the heap then I should write `mytype **p` and then `malloc` just like in the 2. Code ("2. Solution").

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214774/discussion-between-abdalrohman-alsalkhadi-and-adrian-mole).